# Is there a way to tell what killed a specific turret of mine as Symmetra?

Tags: overwatch

As Symmetra, your goal is to place tiny turrets in deviously brilliant places. Sometimes I'll be placing turrets in areas I'm not directly observing. You're notified when a turret is destroyed, but is there any way for me to get more information about what destroys them? That could be helpful in adjusting my strategy mid-match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than having vision over the area, either directly or through Sonar Arrow, Infra-sight, there is no notification about it whatsoever. They're treated the same as Widowmaker's mines, and both of Junkrat's placeables.

Answer (score 2):

You can't know who destroys them, but you can know when they're fighting because they'll have a small ! over their icon.